# TCL text file string to variable

Tags: variables, tcl

I am reading set of lines from text file. It's laid out like this

```
kCode %title My Title
kCode %content Hello World
pCode %picture MyVar
```

I have MyVar defined:

```
set MyVar fox
set code [lindex $line 0]  ;#Set code to retrieve xCode from text file
set morph [lindex $line 2] ;#Set morph to the actual value from text file
```

With a conditional if statement

```
if { $code eq "pCode" } {
puts "I found a picture which is $morph" ;#outputs MyVar
}
```

However, I am struggling to recall the value of the variable defined within the text file.

The closest, I've had is

```
set animal [eval $$morph] ;#references MyVar value which is fox as previously defined
```

But I get

```
invalid command name "fox"
```

Ultimately, I just want to output or save to a variable "fox" from the defined MyVar but cant seem to find the right combination.

I'm sure this is so simple but .. stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `set` procedure accepts 1 or 2 parameters and returns the actual value for variable: 1) name of variable 2) value to be assigned to variable. If the second parameter is not specified, then the variable will not be changed. So, the simplest solution is to call the `set` procedure with only variable name. In your example:

```
set animal [set $morph]
```

Comment: Wow, how embarrassing. Thank you for replying and descriptive text.